# How would changing facebook app id in my app affect previously signed up users

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

We built an iOS app and released it on App Store with a Facebook App Id, which was created by one of our developers using his own Facebook user.

Now, the developer has left and we need to alter a few settings of the app, but we do not have his login credentials to login as him. I know it should not have been this way to start with.

We do have the Facebook App Id, in the code.

What are possible solutions to this:

1. Is it possible to transfer the app to another user?
2. If I create a new app with another user and use the new Facebook App Id, how would it affect existing users of my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a new app it will have an entirely different app id and secret. Your users would have to sign up for the new app. You would not be able to migrate the users to your new app, they would have to authorise it as if starting from scratch.

What you need is to get the old developer to add one of your accounts as an admin role to the existing app. This would give you complete control over it. Obviously this involves getting in touch with your previous developer and hoping they are nice enough to do it!

There is a section called "roles" on the dashboard for an app. This is where they will need to add your account.

Comment: this is kinda old question but it still happens today, im running into this issue, is possible to make a migration somehow without contacting the old developer? (things didnt go well)